# conflicting types for 'libintl_gettextparse'

Tags: linux

I'm trying to compile a linux file system (uclinux-rootfs) for an embedded system. I get the following error logs and compile fails.

I made some search but could not understand what it is.
How can i solve it?

My gcc version is 4.8.4 and I use Ubuntu 14.04

Regards

```
plural.c:185:5: error: conflicting types for 'libintl_gettextparse'
plural-exp.h:106:12: note: previous declaration of 'libintl_gettextparse' was here
plural.c:1106:1: error: conflicting types for 'libintl_gettextparse'
plural-exp.h:106:12: note: previous declaration of 'libintl_gettextparse' was here
plural.c: In function 'libintl_gettextparse':
plural.c:1275:7: error: too few arguments to function '__gettextlex'
plural.y:57:12: note: declared here
plural.y:154:29: error: 'arg' undeclared (first use in this function)
plural.y:154:29: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[7]: *** [plural.o] Error 1
make[7]: Leaving directory `/home/mehmet/kernel/bcm_unified/trunk/uclinux-rootfs/user/e2fsprogs/intl'
make[6]: *** [all-libs-recursive] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/mehmet/kernel/bcm_unified/trunk/uclinux-rootfs/user/e2fsprogs'
make[5]: *** [all] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/mehmet/kernel/bcm_unified/trunk/uclinux-rootfs/user/e2fsprogs'
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/mehmet/kernel/bcm_unified/trunk/uclinux-rootfs/user'
make[3]: *** [base_fs] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/mehmet/kernel/bcm_unified/trunk/uclinux-rootfs'
make[2]: *** [box-fs] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mehmet/kernel/bcm_unified/trunk/uclinux-rootfs'
make[1]: *** [box-fs-7231b0] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mehmet/kernel/bcm_unified/trunk/uclinux-rootfs'
development Linux image build failed.
gnumake: *** [kernel] Error 1
```

Comment: I finally solved the problem by installing Bison version 3.0. Follow the steps explained in http://geeksww.com/tutorials/miscellaneous/bison_gnu_parser_generator/installation/installing_bison_gnu_parser_generator_ubuntu_linux.php for 3.0 version (not for 2.3).

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs due to the bison version, and x86 - x64 conflict.

The possible solution can be reached at: https://github.com/zerovm/glibc/commit/9f3f5229848390ae921f77c92f666ca6f0bff

If this modification is applied to the related lib (eglibc, in my case), it solves the compile problem.

In case of the link is broken, the important parts of the patch file is shown below (!!! This is not a precise diff file; it is minimized due to the character limitation !!!):

```
From 9f3f5229848390ae921f77c92f666ca6f0bffc00 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: pkit <pconstantine@gmail.com>
Date: Sun, 17 Aug 2014 15:39:12 +0000
Subject: [PATCH] fixed gettext compatibility with bison 3.0

plural.y was incompatible with newer bison versions
---
 intl/Makefile      |   9 ++
 intl/plural-exp.h  | 126 ----------------
 intl/plural-exp2.h | 126 ++++++++++++++++
 intl/plural-exp3.h | 126 ++++++++++++++++
 intl/plural.y      | 410 -----------------------------------------------------
 intl/plural2.y     | 410 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 intl/plural3.y     | 409 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 7 files changed, 1080 insertions(+), 536 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 intl/plural-exp.h
 create mode 100644 intl/plural-exp2.h
 create mode 100644 intl/plural-exp3.h
 delete mode 100644 intl/plural.y
 create mode 100644 intl/plural2.y
 create mode 100644 intl/plural3.y

diff --git a/intl/Makefile b/intl/Makefile
index 1511edd..601fb57 100644
--- a/intl/Makefile
+++ b/intl/Makefile
@@ -51,6 +51,15 @@ generated = msgs.h mtrace-tst-gettext tst-gettext.mtrace
 generated-dirs := domaindir localedir

 ifneq (no,$(BISON))
+BISONVERGT2 := $(shell expr `bison -V | grep ^bison | sed 's/^.* //' | cut -f1 -d.` \> 2)
+plural.y: plural2.y plural3.y
+ifeq (0,$(BISONVERGT2))
+   cp plural2.y plural.y
+   cp plural-exp2.h plural-exp.h
+else
+   cp plural3.y plural.y
+   cp plural-exp3.h plural-exp.h
+endif
 plural.c: plural.y
    $(BISON) $(BISONFLAGS) $@ $^
 ifeq ($(with-cvs),yes)
diff --git a/intl/plural-exp.h b/intl/plural-exp.h
deleted file mode 100644
index 4a7336e..0000000
--- a/intl/plural-exp.h
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,126 +0,0 @@

......

diff --git a/intl/plural-exp2.h b/intl/plural-exp2.h
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..4a7336e
--- /dev/null
+++ b/intl/plural-exp2.h
@@ -0,0 +1,126 @@

......
diff --git a/intl/plural-exp3.h b/intl/plural-exp3.h
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..282c15d
--- /dev/null
+++ b/intl/plural-exp3.h
@@ -0,0 +1,126 @@
+/* Expression parsing and evaluation for plural form selection.
+   Copyright (C) 2000, 2001, 2002, 2005, 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
+   Written by Ulrich Drepper <drepper@cygnus.com>, 2000.
+   This file is part of the GNU C Library.
+
+   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
+   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
+   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
+   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
+
+   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
+   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
+   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
+   Lesser General Public License for more details.
+
+   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
+   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, write to the Free
+   Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA
+   02111-1307 USA.  */
+
+#ifndef _PLURAL_EXP_H
+#define _PLURAL_EXP_H
+
+#ifndef PARAMS
+# if __STDC__ || defined __GNUC__ || defined __SUNPRO_C || defined __cplusplus || __PROTOTYPES
+#  define PARAMS(args) args
+# else
+#  define PARAMS(args) ()
+# endif
+#endif
+
+#ifndef internal_function
+# define internal_function
+#endif
+
+#ifndef attribute_hidden
+# define attribute_hidden
+#endif
+
+
+/* This is the representation of the expressions to determine the
+   plural form.  */
+struct expression
+{
+  int nargs;           /* Number of arguments.  */
+  enum operator
+  {
+    /* Without arguments:  */
+    var,           /* The variable "n".  */
+    num,           /* Decimal number.  */
+    /* Unary operators:  */
+    lnot,          /* Logical NOT.  */
+    /* Binary operators:  */
+    mult,          /* Multiplication.  */
+    divide,            /* Division.  */
+    module,            /* Modulo operation.  */
+    plus,          /* Addition.  */
+    minus,         /* Subtraction.  */
+    less_than,         /* Comparison.  */
+    greater_than,      /* Comparison.  */
+    less_or_equal,     /* Comparison.  */
+    greater_or_equal,      /* Comparison.  */
+    equal,         /* Comparison for equality.  */
+    not_equal,         /* Comparison for inequality.  */
+    land,          /* Logical AND.  */
+    lor,           /* Logical OR.  */
+    /* Ternary operators:  */
+    qmop           /* Question mark operator.  */
+  } operation;
+  union
+  {
+    unsigned long int num; /* Number value for `num'.  */
+    struct expression *args[3];    /* Up to three arguments.  */
+  } val;
+};
+
+/* This is the data structure to pass information to the parser and get
+   the result in a thread-safe way.  */
+struct parse_args
+{
+  const char *cp;
+  struct expression *res;
+};
+
+
+/* Names for the libintl functions are a problem.  This source code is used
+   1. in the GNU C Library library,
+   2. in the GNU libintl library,
+   3. in the GNU gettext tools.
+   The function names in each situation must be different, to allow for
+   binary incompatible changes in 'struct expression'.  Furthermore,
+   1. in the GNU C Library library, the names have a __ prefix,
+   2.+3. in the GNU libintl library and in the GNU gettext tools, the names
+         must follow ANSI C and not start with __.
+   So we have to distinguish the three cases.  */
+#ifdef _LIBC
+# define FREE_EXPRESSION __gettext_free_exp
+# define PLURAL_PARSE __gettextparse
+# define GERMANIC_PLURAL __gettext_germanic_plural
+# define EXTRACT_PLURAL_EXPRESSION __gettext_extract_plural
+#elif defined (IN_LIBINTL)
+# define FREE_EXPRESSION libintl_gettext_free_exp
+# define PLURAL_PARSE libintl_gettextparse
+# define GERMANIC_PLURAL libintl_gettext_germanic_plural
+# define EXTRACT_PLURAL_EXPRESSION libintl_gettext_extract_plural
+#else
+# define FREE_EXPRESSION free_plural_expression
+# define PLURAL_PARSE parse_plural_expression
+# define GERMANIC_PLURAL germanic_plural
+# define EXTRACT_PLURAL_EXPRESSION extract_plural_expression
+#endif
+
+extern void FREE_EXPRESSION PARAMS ((struct expression *exp))
+     internal_function;
+extern int PLURAL_PARSE PARAMS ((struct parse_args *arg));
+extern const struct expression GERMANIC_PLURAL attribute_hidden;
+extern void EXTRACT_PLURAL_EXPRESSION PARAMS
+  ((const char *nullentry, const struct expression **pluralp,
+    unsigned long int *npluralsp)) internal_function;
+
+#if !defined (_LIBC) && !defined (IN_LIBINTL)
+extern unsigned long int plural_eval PARAMS ((const struct expression *pexp,
+                         unsigned long int n));
+#endif
+
+#endif /* _PLURAL_EXP_H */
diff --git a/intl/plural.y b/intl/plural.y
deleted file mode 100644
index a1ffb9e..0000000
--- a/intl/plural.y
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,410 +0,0 @@

......

diff --git a/intl/plural2.y b/intl/plural2.y
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..a1ffb9e
--- /dev/null
+++ b/intl/plural2.y
@@ -0,0 +1,410 @@

.......

diff --git a/intl/plural3.y b/intl/plural3.y
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..f3ae954
--- /dev/null
+++ b/intl/plural3.y
@@ -0,0 +1,409 @@
+%{
+/* Expression parsing for plural form selection.
+   Copyright (C) 2000, 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
+   This file is part of the GNU C Library.
+   Written by Ulrich Drepper <drepper@cygnus.com>, 2000.
+
+   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
+   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
+   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
+   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
+
+   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
+   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
+   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
+   Lesser General Public License for more details.
+
+   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
+   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, write to the Free
+   Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA
+   02111-1307 USA.  */
+
+/* The bison generated parser uses alloca.  AIX 3 forces us to put this
+   declaration at the beginning of the file.  The declaration in bison's
+   skeleton file comes too late.  This must come before <config.h>
+   because <config.h> may include arbitrary system headers.  */
+#if defined _AIX && !defined __GNUC__
+ #pragma alloca
+#endif
+#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
+# include <config.h>
+#endif
+
+#include <stddef.h>
+#include <stdlib.h>
+#include <string.h>
+#include "plural-exp.h"
+
+/* The main function generated by the parser is called __gettextparse,
+   but we want it to be called PLURAL_PARSE.  */
+#ifndef _LIBC
+# define __gettextparse PLURAL_PARSE
+#endif
+%}
+%param {struct parse_args *arg}
+%define api.pure full
+%expect 7
+
+%union {
+  unsigned long int num;
+  enum operator op;
+  struct expression *exp;
+}
+
+%{
+/* Prototypes for local functions.  */
+static struct expression *new_exp PARAMS ((int nargs, enum operator op,
+                      struct expression * const *args));
+static inline struct expression *new_exp_0 PARAMS ((enum operator op));
+static inline struct expression *new_exp_1 PARAMS ((enum operator op,
+                          struct expression *right));
+static struct expression *new_exp_2 PARAMS ((enum operator op,
+                        struct expression *left,
+                        struct expression *right));
+static inline struct expression *new_exp_3 PARAMS ((enum operator op,
+                          struct expression *bexp,
+                          struct expression *tbranch,
+                          struct expression *fbranch));
+static int yylex PARAMS ((YYSTYPE *lval, struct parse_args *arg));
+static void yyerror PARAMS ((struct parse_args *arg, const char *str));
+
+/* Allocation of expressions.  */
+
+static struct expression *
+new_exp (nargs, op, args)
+     int nargs;
+     enum operator op;
+     struct expression * const *args;
+{
+  int i;
+  struct expression *newp;
+
+  /* If any of the argument could not be malloc'ed, just return NULL.  */
+  for (i = nargs - 1; i >= 0; i--)
+    if (args[i] == NULL)
+      goto fail;
+
+  /* Allocate a new expression.  */
+  newp = (struct expression *) malloc (sizeof (*newp));
+  if (newp != NULL)
+    {
+      newp->nargs = nargs;
+      newp->operation = op;
+      for (i = nargs - 1; i >= 0; i--)
+   newp->val.args[i] = args[i];
+      return newp;
+    }
+
+ fail:
+  for (i = nargs - 1; i >= 0; i--)
+    FREE_EXPRESSION (args[i]);
+
+  return NULL;
+}
+
+static inline struct expression *
+new_exp_0 (op)
+     enum operator op;
+{
+  return new_exp (0, op, NULL);
+}
+
+static inline struct expression *
+new_exp_1 (op, right)
+     enum operator op;
+     struct expression *right;
+{
+  struct expression *args[1];
+
+  args[0] = right;
+  return new_exp (1, op, args);
+}
+
+static struct expression *
+new_exp_2 (op, left, right)
+     enum operator op;
+     struct expression *left;
+     struct expression *right;
+{
+  struct expression *args[2];
+
+  args[0] = left;
+  args[1] = right;
+  return new_exp (2, op, args);
+}
+
+static inline struct expression *
+new_exp_3 (op, bexp, tbranch, fbranch)
+     enum operator op;
+     struct expression *bexp;
+     struct expression *tbranch;
+     struct expression *fbranch;
+{
+  struct expression *args[3];
+
+  args[0] = bexp;
+  args[1] = tbranch;
+  args[2] = fbranch;
+  return new_exp (3, op, args);
+}
+
+%}
+
+/* This declares that all operators have the same associativity and the
+   precedence order as in C.  See [Harbison, Steele: C, A Reference Manual].
+   There is no unary minus and no bitwise operators.
+   Operators with the same syntactic behaviour have been merged into a single
+   token, to save space in the array generated by bison.  */
+%right '?'     /*   ?      */
+%left '|'      /*   ||     */
+%left '&'      /*   &&     */
+%left EQUOP2       /*   == !=  */
+%left CMPOP2       /*   < > <= >=  */
+%left ADDOP2       /*   + -    */
+%left MULOP2       /*   * / %  */
+%right '!'     /*   !      */
+
+%token <op> EQUOP2 CMPOP2 ADDOP2 MULOP2
+%token <num> NUMBER
+%type <exp> exp
+
+%%
+
+start:   exp
+     {
+       if ($1 == NULL)
+         YYABORT;
+       arg->res = $1;
+     }
+   ;
+
+exp:     exp '?' exp ':' exp
+     {
+       $$ = new_exp_3 (qmop, $1, $3, $5);
+     }
+   | exp '|' exp
+     {
+       $$ = new_exp_2 (lor, $1, $3);
+     }
+   | exp '&' exp
+     {
+       $$ = new_exp_2 (land, $1, $3);
+     }
+   | exp EQUOP2 exp
+     {
+       $$ = new_exp_2 ($2, $1, $3);
+     }
+   | exp CMPOP2 exp
+     {
+       $$ = new_exp_2 ($2, $1, $3);
+     }
+   | exp ADDOP2 exp
+     {
+       $$ = new_exp_2 ($2, $1, $3);
+     }
+   | exp MULOP2 exp
+     {
+       $$ = new_exp_2 ($2, $1, $3);
+     }
+   | '!' exp
+     {
+       $$ = new_exp_1 (lnot, $2);
+     }
+   | 'n'
+     {
+       $$ = new_exp_0 (var);
+     }
+   | NUMBER
+     {
+       if (($$ = new_exp_0 (num)) != NULL)
+         $$->val.num = $1;
+     }
+   | '(' exp ')'
+     {
+       $$ = $2;
+     }
+   ;
+
+%%
+
+void
+internal_function
+FREE_EXPRESSION (exp)
+     struct expression *exp;
+{
+  if (exp == NULL)
+    return;
+
+  /* Handle the recursive case.  */
+  switch (exp->nargs)
+    {
+    case 3:
+      FREE_EXPRESSION (exp->val.args[2]);
+      /* FALLTHROUGH */
+    case 2:
+      FREE_EXPRESSION (exp->val.args[1]);
+      /* FALLTHROUGH */
+    case 1:
+      FREE_EXPRESSION (exp->val.args[0]);
+      /* FALLTHROUGH */
+    default:
+      break;
+    }
+
+  free (exp);
+}
+
+
+static int
+yylex (lval, arg)
+     YYSTYPE *lval;
+     struct parse_args *arg;
+{
+  const char *exp = arg->cp;
+  int result;
+
+  while (1)
+    {
+      if (exp[0] == '\0')
+   {
+     arg->cp = exp;
+     return YYEOF;
+   }
+
+      if (exp[0] != ' ' && exp[0] != '\t')
+   break;
+
+      ++exp;
+    }
+
+  result = *exp++;
+  switch (result)
+    {
+    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
+    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
+      {
+   unsigned long int n = result - '0';
+   while (exp[0] >= '0' && exp[0] <= '9')
+     {
+       n *= 10;
+       n += exp[0] - '0';
+       ++exp;
+     }
+   lval->num = n;
+   result = NUMBER;
+      }
+      break;
+
+    case '=':
+      if (exp[0] == '=')
+   {
+     ++exp;
+     lval->op = equal;
+     result = EQUOP2;
+   }
+      else
+   result = YYERRCODE;
+      break;
+
+    case '!':
+      if (exp[0] == '=')
+   {
+     ++exp;
+     lval->op = not_equal;
+     result = EQUOP2;
+   }
+      break;
+
+    case '&':
+    case '|':
+      if (exp[0] == result)
+   ++exp;
+      else
+   result = YYERRCODE;
+      break;
+
+    case '<':
+      if (exp[0] == '=')
+   {
+     ++exp;
+     lval->op = less_or_equal;
+   }
+      else
+   lval->op = less_than;
+      result = CMPOP2;
+      break;
+
+    case '>':
+      if (exp[0] == '=')
+   {
+     ++exp;
+     lval->op = greater_or_equal;
+   }
+      else
+   lval->op = greater_than;
+      result = CMPOP2;
+      break;
+
+    case '*':
+      lval->op = mult;
+      result = MULOP2;
+      break;
+
+    case '/':
+      lval->op = divide;
+      result = MULOP2;
+      break;
+
+    case '%':
+      lval->op = module;
+      result = MULOP2;
+      break;
+
+    case '+':
+      lval->op = plus;
+      result = ADDOP2;
+      break;
+
+    case '-':
+      lval->op = minus;
+      result = ADDOP2;
+      break;
+
+    case 'n':
+    case '?':
+    case ':':
+    case '(':
+    case ')':
+      /* Nothing, just return the character.  */
+      break;
+
+    case ';':
+    case '\n':
+    case '\0':
+      /* Be safe and let the user call this function again.  */
+      --exp;
+      result = YYEOF;
+      break;
+
+    default:
+      result = YYERRCODE;
+#if YYDEBUG != 0
+      --exp;
+#endif
+      break;
+    }
+
+  arg->cp = exp; 
+
+  return result;
+}
+
+
+static void
+yyerror (arg, str)
+     struct parse_args *arg;
+     const char *str;
+{
+  /* Do nothing.  We don't print error messages here.  */
+}
```

In short:

- plural-exp.h is moved to plural-exp2.h
- plural.y is moved to plural2.y
- plural-exp3.h and plural3.y are created
- related header and y file is chosen according to the bison version